# Retrieving Children from Multiple Parent Types, and Associating Them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What is the most efficient way to

a) retrieve all children objects from multiple parent types, and

b) know what the parent type is and the exact parent Id for each child?

Currently this is what I'm doing and it's incredibly inefficient, at least the part where I find the specific parent of each child.

```
public class ChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParentType1Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ParentType2Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildModel> Children { get; set; }
}

//Get all ChildModels from ParentType1
var parentType1Children = db.ParentType1Models
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .ToList();

listOfChildModels.AddRange(parentType1Children);

//Get all ChildModels from ParentType2
var parentType2Children = db.ParentType2Models
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .ToList();

listOfChildModels.AddRange(parentType2Children);


//Find the parent for each ChildModel
foreach (var child in listOfChildModels)
{
    ParentType1Model parentType1ModelCheck = null;
    ParentType2Model parentType2ModelCheck = null;

    parentType1ModelCheck = await db.ParentType1Models 
        .Where(p => p.Children
        .Any(i => i.Id == child.Id))
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    //If first check is null, then move to second check
    if (taskProjectModelCheck == null)
    {
        parentType2ModelCheck = await db.ParentType2Models 
            .Where(p => p.Children
            .Any(i => i.Id == child.Id))
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    //Now record the parent type and parent Id in an object containing the original ChildModel and it's parent's info (to be used later for various things)
    ChildViewModel childViewModel = new ChildViewModel();
    childViewModel.ChildModel = child;
    if (parentType1ModelCheck != null)
    {
        childViewModel.ParentType = "ParentType1";
        childViewModel.ParentModelId = parentType1ModelCheck.Id;
    }

    else if (parentType2ModelCheck != null)
    {
        childViewModel.ParentType = "ParentType2";
        childViewModel.ParentModelId = parentType2ModelCheck.Id;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using raw SQL, and it is extremely fast.
By writing a query directly against the database, I was able to go straight to the many to many relationship tables that get created by Entity Framework when I set up the ParentTypeXModels and ChildModels.

```
result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ANewChildObject>(
"select 
    ParentModelId = pm.Id, 
    Id = c.Id, 
    ParentType = 'ParentType1'  
from dbo.ChildModels c 
    JOIN dbo.ParentType1ModelsChildModels pmT ON c.Id = pmT.ChildModel_Id 
    JOIN dbo.ParentType1Models pm on pmT.ParentType1Model_Id = pm.Id 

UNION ALL

 select 
    ParentModelId = pm.Id, 
    Id = c.Id, 
    ParentType = 'ParentType2'  
from dbo.ChildModels c 
    JOIN dbo.ParentType2ModelsChildModels pmT ON c.Id = pmT.ChildModel_Id 
    JOIN dbo.ParentType2Models pm on pmT.ParentType2Model_Id = pm.Id" 
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
var ids1 = from p in db.ParentType1Models
            from c in p.Children
            select new
            {
                parentId = p.Id,
                parentName = p.Name,
                childName = c.Name,
                childId = c.Id,
                ParentType = "One"
            };


var ids2 = from p in db.ParentType2Models
            from c in p.Children
            select new
            {
                parentId = p.Id,
                parentName = p.Name,
                childName = c.Name,
                childId = c.Id,
                ParentType = "Two"
            };

var results = ids1.Union(ids2).ToList();
```

Comment: This simplified and shortened the code, but ultimately it added around 3x to the response time.

Comment: @amartin That's unfortunate. I included the names for demonstration. Perhaps limiting to just ids would allow it to hit the indexes only. Hard to know without seeing the query plan.

Comment: I believe you're right but unfortunately I need a lot of the properties from the ChildModels.